# How to write tests for static routes defined in app.yaml?

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine

I have quite a few static files used in my Google App Engine application (CSS, robots.txt, etc.) They are all defined in app.yaml.

I want to have some automated tests that check whether those definitions in app.yaml are valid and my latest changes didn't brake anything. E.g. check that specific URLs return correct responses. Ideally, it should be a part of my app unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

I have a post deploy script for the staging environment that just does curl on the urls to validate they are all there. If this script passes (among other things) I will deploy from staging to production.

Comment: And something similar for the local development environment? Something that I can do before checking in changes.

Comment: You can do the same thing for dev_server

Comment: Good point. Just need to make sure that development server is up and serving the correct version of the application.